# Error formulario en html5 en un webview desde swift

Tags: html5, ios, swift2, webview

Esto haciendo una app que muestra un formulario `html` dentro de un `webview`. 
En el formulario tengo los siguientes campos:

- Titulo
- Descripcion
- Imagen(input file)

Si no añado imagen, todo va bien, pero si selecciono una imagen a traves del input, me recarga solo el formulario, por lo que me borra los datos previamente introducidos.

Mi html:

```
<div class="container">
    <form role="form" id="commentForm" action="/new" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Titulo</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="titulo" required="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Descripcion</label>
            <textarea name="desc" style="height: 100px; width: 100%; resize: none;" required=""></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Imagen</label>
            <input type="file" class="form-control" name="nombre_archivo" >
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Crear Oferta</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Mi código de swift:

```
class NavegadorViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate  {

    var url: String?

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var carga: UIActivityIndicatorView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
        self.webView.delegate = self
        carga.startAnimating()

    }

    func webViewDidStartLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
        carga.startAnimating()
    }

    func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView){
        carga.stopAnimating()
        carga.hidden = true
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        let url:NSURL? = NSURL(string: self.url!)
        if let actualUrl = url {
            let urlRequest:NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: actualUrl)
            self.webView.loadRequest(urlRequest)
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func dismissViewControllerAnimated(flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)?) {
        if self.presentedViewController != nil {
            super.dismissViewControllerAnimated(flag, completion: completion)
        }
    }
}
```

Cual puede ser el problema?? Tengo que cambiar algo del `html` o de swift??

Comment: Tiene pinta que al seleccionar un archivo está haciendo un `postback` del forumario. Quizá guardando en variables de sesión los valores cuándo se modifican y recargando en el onload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He encontrado la respuesta [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17302848/ios-6-html-input-file-tag-doesnt-work-if-load-the-web-page-in-uiwebview).

El error estaba en que tenia que se cargara el webview en la funcion `viewDidAppear`, entonces cuando seleccionaba un file, al volver a aprecer el navegador volvia a usarse esa función, ahora el código lo he puesto en la función: `viewDidLoad`

Mi código ahora está asi:

```
class NavegadorViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate  {

    var url: String?

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var carga: UIActivityIndicatorView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
        self.webView.delegate = self
        carga.startAnimating()

        let url:NSURL? = NSURL(string: self.url!)
        if let actualUrl = url {
            let urlRequest:NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: actualUrl)
            self.webView.loadRequest(urlRequest)
        }
    }

    func webViewDidStartLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
        carga.startAnimating()
    }

    func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView){
        carga.stopAnimating()
        carga.hidden = true
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        /*let url:NSURL? = NSURL(string: self.url!)
        if let actualUrl = url {
            let urlRequest:NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: actualUrl)
            self.webView.loadRequest(urlRequest)
        }*/
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func dismissViewControllerAnimated(flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)?) {
        if self.presentedViewController != nil {
            super.dismissViewControllerAnimated(flag, completion: completion)
        }
    }
}
```